# python pandas | conditional aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

| volume | price | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2021-09-29 04:00:00 |
| 300 | 2 | 2021-09-29 05:30:00 |
| 700 | 5 | 2021-09-29 06:00:00 |
| 500 | 9 | 2021-09-29 06:30:00 |
| 900 | 22 | 2021-09-29 07:00:00 |
| 400 | 29 | 2021-09-29 07:30:00 |

Can you help me with the  below aggregation?

Add the volume before 2021-09-29 07:15:00  and after 2021-09-29 05:45:00 (expected result should be 2100)

Add the volume if price is greater than 20. (Expected result  is 1300)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Loading the data
dt = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep="\t")
dt['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['time'])

# Aggregation by price
dt_price = dt.groupby(dt['price'] > 20)[["volume"]].sum()
dt_price.index.name = "price > 20"

# Aggregation by time
start_time = datetime.time(5,45)
end_time = datetime.time(7,15)

dt_time = dt.groupby((dt['time'].dt.time > start_time) & (dt['time'].dt.time < end_time))[["volume"]].sum()
dt_time.index.name = "In Interval?"

print(dt_price)
print(dt_time)
```

**Output**

```
            volume
price > 20
False         1600
True          1300

              volume
In Interval?
False            800
True            2100
```